# Are Vue 3 `reactive` object getters made into computed values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In this example, is `bookCount` memoized the same way as a `computed` ref is?

```
const author = reactive({
  name: 'John Doe',
  books: [
    'Vue 2 - Advanced Guide',
    'Vue 3 - Basic Guide',
    'Vue 4 - The Mystery'
  ],

  get bookCount() {
    return this.books.length
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. The getter will be executed everytime the property is accessed.

You can check it by using the getter in the template, and provoke a template re-render. You'll see the getter will be executed at every render, while a regular `computed` won't (as long as the value didn't change).

Check out this example on [sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: FYI, you can make `bookCount` a `computed` inside the `reactive` object, and it will work seamlessly :)

Comment: It causes some issues with TypeScript though, since it doesn't know the type of `this` and complains about a circular reference if using `author`